# Unstable Unicorns - what is the definition of "effect"?

Tags: unstable-unicorns

There is a card 'blinding light' that says 'all your unicorns are treated as basic unicorns with no special effects' -  But what is a special effect?  The rules define obvious words like "draw" and "play" but not "effect".

For example, 'annoying flying unicorn' has the text:

> When this card enters your Stable, you may choose a player. That
> player must DISCARD a card. If this card is sacrificed or destroyed,
> return it to your hand.

What part of that is an effect? Is it the second half of the sentence, "discard a card"?  Is it the whole sentence, "That player must DISCARD a card"?  Is it only the condition?  The action?  Sentences with "may" in it?  Maybe its the second sentence - "Return it to your hand"!?

(I have a friend who says the second part is not an effect.  Therefore if I play 'blinding light' and then 'unicorn poison' on her card, she gets to put the card back in her hand.  The reasonings are many - there is an element of choice in the second part, or because the card is no long in the stable, or maybe because it is the third sentence in the card.  Point is, 'effect' is not defined.')

So can anyone define 'effect'?

Comment: There's another question with an answer regarding this card on this site: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/44587/what-are-triggered-effects-in-unstable-unicorns?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Blinding Light treats your unicorns as if they have no text on them at all, except "Basic Unicorn." So if the Annoying Flying Unicorn is sacrificed or destroyed in your stable, it just gets discarded like any other dead unicorn. When you play a unicorn into a stable that already has Blinding Light, it does nothing – just like a Basic Unicorn.

When I looked up Blinding Light, I found this image, which has much less ambiguous text:

[image]

No mention of "special" effects, just all Unicorn card effects, i.e. all of the text at the bottom of a Unicorn card. (If your Unicorns were all Pandas, they would be unaffected by this card.)

Comment: Blinding Light has had [a variety of texts](http://unstablegameswiki.com/index.php?title=UU_-_Blinding_Light) in various printings.